# RedirectMatch Querystring on Root

Tags: apache-2.2, redirection

I'm trying to configure a Redirect:

I want to send only the root page of www.website.com to www.website.com/?lang=id

However, if I use the below it will get stuck in an infinite loop as I'm not checking against the querystring value with the Match condition:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /?lang=id
```

How do I do this?

Comment: AFAIK the `RedirectMatch` doesn't take GET parameters into account and you'll have to use mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

@HBruijn is correct. You will need to use Mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang=id
RewriteRule (.*) $1?land=id [R=302,L]
```

**EDIT:** ^ not 100% sure is -absolutely- correct letter for letter, but it will point you in the right  direction at least - feel free to edit my answer and I'll approve your change when you get it working :)